# Got a new hard drive and would like to setup file system

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, file-management

I just finished assembling a new computer. I installed Windows 7 on my 250GB SSD, and everything is working fine. I've now plugged a 1TB HDD, and formatted it to allow windows to place files on it. Currently there is nothing in it. It's empty. Top level has nothing.

I would like to move files between the main hard drive and the HDD, but I'd have to manually build the file system. How can I place an empty file system on the hard drive so that when I move files I know where to place them and Windows knows where to look?

Basically, I want to use the default directory structure of Windows' system drive as a guideline of where to store my files.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25446/discussion-on-question-by-meed96-got-a-new-hard-drive-and-would-like-to-setup-fi).

Comment: @Sathya: "Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements." There were many, but I feel there was no extended discussion. The comments were used as intended and provided a lot of vital information. Can I suggest the most important ones be moved back?

Comment: @MarcksThomas those as such should have been edited back into the post,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your main concern is to avoid making a mess of your second hard drive and you're looking to the default directory structure of Windows's system drive as an example of how to organise your files neatly. This is not the main purpose of this structure; these directories have a specific meaning in Windows. For example, program files belong in *the* program files directory (`%PROGRAMFILES%`), which usually happens to be `C:\Program Files`. You can rename it if you like trouble, but Windows by design requires there to be exactly one. You can also create something in parallel called `D:\Program Files`, but it will not be the program files directory. For that reason, I find this naming scheme to be the very opposite of a clean directory structure on a second hard drive, which is why you will have difficulty finding tools that do it automatically.

It is also because these directories have meaning that you cannot necessarily move items out of them without breaking anything. Most notably, programs themselves of which the installer created references to their location in the registry, but it's also true for files in the user space, e.g. application data or even regular documents that inherit file permissions from their location in the users directory.

Uninstalling and reinstalling software to a different location/drive is the regular way of 'moving' non-portable programs, but a potentially preferable alternative is to physically move the files to a better suited drive, using whatever naming scheme you like, then creating a symbolic link to the new location. That way, you can virtually store 1 TB of programs in the default directory on your 250 GB SSD.

Finally, should anyone nonetheless wish to recreate the directory structure of an existing drive, here is a command to do just that:

```
robocopy C:\ D:\ /XF * /E /LEV:2 /CREATE /COPYALL
```

This requires elevation. It mirrors the first two levels (`/LEV:2`, counting root as the first, so this goes no deeper than `C:\Windows`) of the directory structure on `C:\` to `D:\`.

Comment: Also, don't do it. I tested whether I got the command right. I did. I am now in NTFS hell trying to undo the mess I've made. =[

Comment: Oh boy...hope you figure it out...

Comment: @MarcksThomas Edit your post to remove the bad advice please.